# Spring boot 2 actuator closes connections under heavy load

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I don't yet have a working bug-reproducing scenario (working on it), but under heavy load (that's slightly above 200 requests per second) spring actuator's health endpoint occasionally gives:

```
Error [reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException] for HTTP GET "/actuator/health", but ServerHttpResponse already committed (200 OK)
```

There's no additional stack trace or other error message in the output/logs.

The consequence is that the connection to the client is closed server-side before any response is sent out. When running in a pod in kubernetes, this causes the container to be rebooted. This is annoying and resource-wasting, when happening once for each container every (very) few minutes.

The project uses spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE and spring cloud Hoxton.SR1, and is built using spring-webflux.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Looks like a bug, try to ask in https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor

Comment: I asked - got no reaction so far.

Comment: any solutions yet?

Comment: @TunaYagci I was pressed by other, more important things, and didn't get to further investigate this. We got rid of the problem by not using actuator to publish our custom metrics, and scaling out. With only a handful of the default metrics, and other, app-specific, custom metrics published through a custom endpoint, we don't see this anymore. That is of course a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @user625488 Did you get to the root cause of this error?

Comment: @Amardeep Sorry, no. Just the workaround described in my previous comment. Proved to be very hard to generate the bug reproducibly, and spring boot has had quite a few new releases since then.

Comment: It's been a year since you published that question and it still seems to be an ongoing issue. I'm eperiencing exactly the same thing ;/